# PHP caching - am I missing something obvious?

Tags: php, xampp

Let me preface this with; I do not work with PHP. The code below is something that we inherited and look after. It talks to Google Sheets to display information onto some TV's around an office, and thats it. The company who set this up originally have ceased trading, so we can't go to them for information or ask them how to fix it, so I thought I'd come here.

Whenever I go to http://ServerIP/FileName.php?u=Sales/ it returns the error "Google failure and nothing to display from cache" which is defined near the bottom of the code, however, I've no idea how to get it work. I can also see on line 62, there is this - `"${${"GLOBALS"}["kjvieqjie"]}="cache/".${${"GLOBALS"}["bjlwuz"]};`" which I've tried to change to c:/Xampp/htdocs/cache and to no avail.

This runs from a Windows Server running Xampp - ive ensured that in the folder the php file lives in, there is a folder called "Cache" and that read/write permissions are set to full control for the Everyone group, so i can't see this being a permission issue, but i could easily be wrong.

Code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/VMKxg3gM)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need anything to assist with the resolution of this, let me know :)

Comment: Please share the code in question, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: After having looked in the posted code: that's highly obfuscated and I doubt that anybody here will debug that code for you

Comment: Hiya Nico,
Thank you for the response - that doesn't surprise me - having looked a lot at it myself it seemed like it was done in the most complicated way ever for no reason at all.

As for debugging, I've attempted to change any and all reference to /cache/ to c:/xampp/htdocs/cache, and had a look at the naming structure of the existing files in that folder, and created new ones to match but still to no avail - as if the xampp service can't see or can't read the files

Comment: Replace the ServerIp with the proper ip.

Comment: I was only using that as an example, it is going to the actual IP of the server but still no dice